# I wonder if I can get >116 simple linear shapes to use them as a Alphabet?

Tags: typography

I'm just asking if that's **possible** to have ~116 simply drawn signs that can be related -since it's already proved that humans are more quick in writing linked alphabets in the same word-, easy for handwriting, and learning.

In fact, those alphabet I wanna create are sets of 4 forms for each letter.

for example:
 [image: Just a quick example]

---

**Edit:**

I'm working on a project where I need to make letters for the real sounds not the alphabet, i.e. New simple signs for representing The English Phonetics, Instead of having /fəˈnɛtɪks/ we can write it -by hand also- as : [image]

All I'm asking for is, **is that even possible?**

Comment: Sounds like you're working on something interesting! Hand lettering is surely related to graphic design, but I'm not exactly clear on how we can help you. What sort of answers are you hoping to gather?

Comment: @John Thank You, that was awesome (: . and to make it clear: **I am asking If I can** do what I explained before, **116 distinguishable linear shapes**, **can be easily handwritten**, and **designed to be combined and linked while writing**

Comment: There are 26 letters in the English alphabet along with the numerals 0-9. If you flip each of these on the vertical and/or horizontal axis, you have a base set of 144. Some of them are symmetrical on one or both axes and some will resemble others, but just on this basis alone, I would say your simple answer is "yes."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I think it should be possible.
You should have a look at some shorthand systems.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shorthand

While they are not entirely phonetically based, parts of them are (I'm only familiar with German shorthand, not with English shorthand, so I cannot really tell you how much that is true for the English one).

But from my knowledge about shorthand I could tell you that creating such a system should be possible.

Comment: In fact I knew about shorthand system, but it's somehow difficult to understand and to learn, moreover the parts of the word are not linked, and it contains dots (in some systems) which it make the system more simple but not quick.

Comment: The shorthand system is actually optimized to be as quick as possible and as such has been improved for this purpose over decades and centuries. So it IS extremely fast and if you're good at it you can write faster than people can dictate to you.

Also, it is actually rather easy to learn, my shorthand teacher used to say that you don't have to be very smart to learn it, you just have to keep practicing.

However, what you are aiming for seems to be a bit different and in my opinion should be very possible to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to build 116 shapes using linear (the same spatial relationships) combination of the  smaller building shapes you should use minimum 5 different elements.

5 different elements give you 5!= 120 combinations (shapes, letters etc).

4 possible shapes gives you 4!=25 combinations.

Because the letters are much more complicated then just 1 or 5 elements and there is no such thing as "linear" combinations inside the letters, the task you want to solve is a huge challenge cause human should learn to recognise these strange combinations.

The humanity solved this by thousands of years, I suppose that in Math community you will find more sophisticated answer.

Comment: Not sure the math community can help further. You pretty much covered it: 116 shapes does not require a lot of components. However, the key feature of writing is data extraction, not ease of writing so the real challenge (before getting into how one gets a new system adopted) is error correction and recognition/discrimination.

Comment: @horatio Math community I meant for algebraic calculations of positions, combinations and elements. As you can see, I stated that alphabet which is built from so small shapes group would be very difficult to recognise by us...